# Django class based view giving error

Tags: django

I am creating a class based view to add a new record to the db. Below is how my view looks,

```
class RecordCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ['name','description']
    model = models.Record
    success_url = reverse_lazy("index")
```

This is how my form looks,

```
<form action="{% url 'created' %}" method="post">
                             {% csrf_token %}
                             <input type="text" id="name" name="fname" placeholder="Name">
                             <input type="textarea" id="description" name="fdescription" placeholder="Description">
                        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
                         </form>
```

This is how my url.py file looks,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^create/',views.RecordCreateView.as_view(),name='created'),
       ]
```

Now when I go to the admin page of django(default admin GUI) and try to add a record, I am getting the below error,

```
OperationalError at /admin/my_app/record/add/   
no such table: abi_app_record
```

Any leads here will be helpful.

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner :oops my mistake.thanks for the heads up

Comment: Hmm! weird, I see in the traceback the url `/admin/my_app/record/add/` but this doesn't the url called by your `RecordCreateView`

Comment: @Lemayzeur : I am using a a class based view and the above form code that i put,is inside index page and not a separate template.

Comment: that's what I thought, the code posted is not related to the issue...